# The constructor Timer(int, ClockC.Listener) is undefined

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am watching a tutorial on youtube and here the code I have so far,

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.management.timer.Timer;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ClockC extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JTextField time;
JPanel p1;
public ClockC() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    time = new JTextField(10);
    time.setEditable(false);
    time.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 48));

    p1.add(time);

    add(p1);

    Timer t = new Timer(1000, new Listener);
    t.start();

}
class Listener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
}
```

The problem is when I get to the Timer t = new Timer(1000, new Listener); I get a error saying its unidentified.

Thanks.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new Listener);
```

into

```
Listener listener = new Listener();
Timer t = new Timer(1000, listener);
```

or

```
 Timer t = new Timer(1000, new Listener());
```

You did not define the call to the constructor of `Listener`.

Comment: I stil get the same error. I used Listener listener = new Listener();
Timer t = new Timer(1000, listener);

Comment: What exactly is the error? Compile time or runtime? Can you add it to the post?

Comment: Hey never mind I found out my problem! Thanks for the help anyways guys its nice to know someone will help me if I have more JAVA issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're importing the wrong `Timer`, Java has (at least) three different `Timer` classes

Change `import javax.management.timer.Timer;` to `import javax.swing.Timer`

Then change `Timer t = new Timer(1000, new Listener);` to `Timer t = new Timer(1000, new Listener());`